# How to reload icon in ui preview dynamic

Tags: python

I will try to explain myself as best as possible, in this preset you can get the preview using this function,
the problem is that if I change a png file in the selected directory but keep the same name the function will not update the image since it has already been loaded, I would like to understand how to delete this icon image out of the function, I can do it anywhere is not a problem I do not need to be in the function

```
def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):
    """EnumProperty callback"""
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    wm = context.window_manager
    directory = wm.my_previews_dir

    # Get the preview collection (defined in register func).
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    print("Scanning directory: %s" % directory)

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the directory for png files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(".png"):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # generates a thumbnail preview for a file.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)
            icon = pcoll.get(name)
            if not icon:
                #################################################
                ##problem if i try to reload avoiding the if  condition, get error because is has 
                #already been uploaded
                thumb = pcoll.load(name, filepath, 'IMAGE')
                ##i need to delete 1 item by name so that the image can be loaded
                ###########################################
            else:
                thumb = pcoll[name]
            enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory

    return pcoll.my_previews
```

I don't need to delete in this function , i can delete from my operator button
I try to delete from bpy.utils.previews.remove(preview_collections["main"].pcoll) but i don't know if is a right way.

Edit:
Failing to find an answer this script inside an operator, it works but deletes all the previews and then regenerates them, I have not yet understood how to delete only 1 icon..

```
class Myoperator(bpy.types.Operator):

    def execute(self,context):

        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
        pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
        pcoll.my_previews_dir = ""
        pcoll.my_previews = ()

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

I think this script works for me, even if I have to say that it would be better to delete only the icon in question to avoid having to reload all the icons, I would just need to reload only the icon changed from this preview collection, for now I'll do well, if anyone has any better ideas (or correction) I would be happy